# Bitbucket Pull Request Merge

Tags: merge, bitbucket, pull-request

What I want to achieve is: developers (with write access) should create a branch and a pull request to commit changes. Admins should be allowed to push without creating a pull request directly into the repo.

What I have done on repo:

1. Merge strategy is "fast forward"
2. Branch permission: Developmen(master), Write access "nobody", "Merge via pull request": the developer in question

Result: both of them has to merge by pull request. Pushing in master is remote rejected

Second try: Added the admin to "Write access" and he is automatically added to "Merge via pull request" and in the end, it is the same behaviour.

Is there a possibilty to change settings in "Branch Permissions" to achieve what I want to?

Comment: This kind of permission-setting is specific to the hosting site. I don't know how one does it on Bitbucket. On GitHub you'd give full access to the admin and that would be all you need.